# Symfony2: Scope Widening Exception

Tags: service, symfony, scope

I want to inject a form and formHandler service into my controller.

```
<services>
    <service id="acme_core.image_controller" class="Acme\CoreBundle\Controller\ImageController">
        <argument type="service" id="session" />
        <argument type="service" id="acme_core.image.form" />
        <argument type="service" id="acme_core.image.form.handler" />
        <argument type="service" id="acme_core.image_manager.default" />
    </service>
</services>
```

> Scope Widening Injection detected: The definition "acme_core.image_controller" references the service "acme_core.image.form.handler" which belongs to a narrower scope. Generally, it is safer to either move "acme_core.image_controller" to scope "request" or alternatively rely on the provider pattern by injecting the container itself, and requesting the service "acme_core.image.form.handler" each time it is needed. In rare, special cases however that might not be necessary, then you can set the reference to strict=false to get rid of this error.

What does this mean concret?
What should I add tom my image_controller.xml?

Best Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add `scope="request"` in your service tag e.g

```
<service id="acme_core.image_controller" class="Acme\CoreBundle\Controller\ImageController" scope="request">
```

For more info check [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html) cookbook entry.